# Desperately Need Explanation regarding WMI... Please help

Tags: c#

How can I use `WMIUserID`, `WMIPassword`, `WMIAlternateCredentials` using C#?

Also, is it possible to get remote computer's Administrator-password?

Please try to explain with examples.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you serious about the admin password?

Comment: Well, how am i suppose to setup WMI-Connection to a remote computer using that computer's Administrative rights?

Comment: @Samiul: Depends on the environment. If in a domain, you should connect using a domain administrator account. If in a workgroup, the remote computer needs to add the account you will be using to connect, to its local administrators group. Retrieving a password to an administrator account remotely should obviously be a bit gaping security hole; which is therefore not available as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Her is some example code

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Options;
using System.Security; 

namespace SMAPIQuery
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 

        string computer = "Computer_B";
        string domain = "DOMAIN";
        string username = "AdminUserName";


        string plaintextpassword; 

        Console.WriteLine("Enter password:");
        plaintextpassword = Console.ReadLine(); 

        SecureString securepassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in plaintextpassword)
        {
            securepassword.AppendChar(c);
        } 

        // create Credentials
        CimCredential Credentials = new CimCredential(PasswordAuthenticationMechanism.Default, 
                                                      domain, 
                                                      username, 
                                                      securepassword); 

        // create SessionOptions using Credentials
        WSManSessionOptions SessionOptions = new WSManSessionOptions();
        SessionOptions.AddDestinationCredentials(Credentials); 

        // create Session using computer, SessionOptions
        CimSession Session = CimSession.Create(computer, SessionOptions); 

        var allVolumes = Session.QueryInstances(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume");
        var allPDisks = Session.QueryInstances(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive"); 

        // Loop through all volumes
        foreach (CimInstance oneVolume in allVolumes)
        {
            // Show volume information

            if (oneVolume.CimInstanceProperties["DriveLetter"].ToString()[0] > ' '  )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Volume ‘{0}’ has {1} bytes total, {2} bytes available", 
                                  oneVolume.CimInstanceProperties["DriveLetter"], 
                                  oneVolume.CimInstanceProperties["Size"], 
                                  oneVolume.CimInstanceProperties["SizeRemaining"]);
            }

        } 

        // Loop through all physical disks
        foreach (CimInstance onePDisk in allPDisks)
        {
            // Show physical disk information
            Console.WriteLine("Disk {0} is model {1}, serial number {2}", 
                              onePDisk.CimInstanceProperties["DeviceId"], 
                              onePDisk.CimInstanceProperties["Model"].ToString().TrimEnd(), 
                              onePDisk.CimInstanceProperties["SerialNumber"]);
        } 

        Console.ReadLine();
     }
   }
   }
```